# RegEx to place tags around matched word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, expression

I want to put bold tags around words that match in a string. However, I also need to be able to find the matched words in a url. If possible I would like to have one RegEx for everything.

Here's what I have tried so far:

I have tried `new RegExp("(^|\\s)(" + match.join('|') + ")(\\s|$)","ig")`
and `new RegExp('(\\b)(' + match2.join('|') + ')(\\b)','ig')`

```
//keyword
var keyword = "Donec sed odio bacon dui.";
var match = ["donec", "bacon", "dui"]; //why does it ignore dui???

var reg1 = new RegExp("(^|\\s)(" + match.join('|') + ")(\\s|$)","ig");
//var reg1 = new RegExp('(\\b)(' + match.join('|') + ')(\\b)','ig');
var reg2 = "$1<b>$2</b>$3";

var keyword = keyword.replace(reg1, reg2);

console.log(keyword);
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: FYI Regular expressions, and all of your code, have nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan okay, thanks

Comment: Yes, this approach is insane and will leave you with brittle code. Use an HTML parser to do this job in a much easier, more maintainable way.

Comment: Many options to replace a word with another word ( your case = same word with bold tags around it) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with overlapping matches. And the word `dui` has a full stop after it (it is not a whitespace, nor end of string). Use a word boundary at the end of first regex:

```
var reg1 = new RegExp("(^|\\W)(" + match.join('|') + ")(?!\\w|(?:[^<]*</[^>]+)?>)","ig");
var reg2 = "$1<b>$2</b>";
```

Note that instead of the `\\b`, you can use `(?!\\w)` negative lookahead and instead of `(^|\\s)` you may use `(^|\\W)` to make sure you do not depend upon whitespace around the keywords. The `(?!\\w|(?:[^<]*</[^>]+)?>)` lookahead will fail the match if the keyword happens to be inside an already tagged text.

The second regex requires word boundaries since the words are in between hyphens:

```
var reg3 = new RegExp("\\b(" + match2.join('|') + ")\\b(?!(?:[^<]*</[^>]+)?>)","ig");
var reg4 = "<b>$1</b>";
```

or a more versatile:

```
var reg3 = new RegExp("(^|\\W)(" + match2.join('|') + ")(?!\\w|(?:[^<]*</[^>]+)?>)","ig");
var reg4 = "$1<b>$2</b>";
```

**Also, you need to escape special regex metacharacters your keywords so that they were treated as literal symbols**. See `match.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))`.

See demo (the replacement pattern is the same for both regexps, declared once):

```js
//keyword
var keyword = "Donec <b>sed</b> odio bacon dui.";
var match = ["test.", "donec", "bacon", "dui"];
var reg = new RegExp("(^|\\W)(" + match.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|') + ")(?!\\w|(?:[^<]*</[^>]+)?>)","ig");
var repl = "$1<b>$2</b>";
var keyword = keyword.replace(reg, repl);

console.log(keyword); 

//website
var keyword2 = "http://www.website.co.uk/hey-<b>more hello o</b>-hey-hi"; //doesnt work
var match2 = ["hello", "hey", "b"];
var reg2 = new RegExp("(^|\\W)(" + match2.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|') + ")(?!\\w|(?:[^<]*</[^>]+)?>)","ig");
var keyword2 = keyword2.replace(reg2, repl);

console.log(keyword2);
```

Comment: I added two possible solutions. The ones with `(^|\W)` and `(?!\w)` should work in any context. If it is still not working, please provide a sample string to test.

Comment: Hello, I just did some tests for some reason when I put ..... it shows the end of </b> tag in bold texts. How could I stop this?

Comment: Please share an input string. I think I will add a DOM based solution, it will be less error prone, but I need to have lunch.

Comment: I think I need to escape < and . because I also have a <span> in a string... so "Test is testing is tested <span></span>" when I type ..... in the words to match the span comes up

Comment: You need to escape the dots, not `<`. I added the escaping code.

Comment: Please edit this regex fiddle -  https://regex101.com/r/jD6qV4/1 - to illustrate because I cannot repro.

Comment: Again, what is your input? Note that longer alternatives should come first (because the first one matched "wins" and the regex engine goes on to search for the next match). See https://regex101.com/r/jD6qV4/2

Comment: I have not had success with a JS/JQuery way to do these replacements for now. I do not understand the latest comment of yours, it sounds like a new question.

Answer (score 3):

No need for this complex regex in order to add **bold** for a known word.
Use replace like this:

1)For global **substr** matching (multiple replacements, for partial words to) use:

```
var res = str.replace(/blog/g, "<b>blog</b>");
```

2)For global **word** matching (multiple replacements, for whole words only) use:

```
var res = str.replace(/\bblog\b/g, "<b>blog</b>");
```

Using \b as a word boundary. Notice "-" char is concidered a word boundary.
Much easier to abstract for any word and easier to read your code

Comment: It only performs a single replacement.

Comment: Thanks, added the global match option for multiple replacements.
He can find more options for multiple replacements here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: I think the problem is more complicated since the whole word should only be matched, and in some specific context.

Comment: This will also match "blog" in the middle of other words.

Comment: easily 'fixable' with word boundaries (\b), again from the link i added above, in case he does not want parts of a word replaced. Im adding it to my original answer, Please upvote if you think i covred everything :)