# apply css styling only for keywords using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide only names from my document being displayed. Say for example I have in my html.erb file:

```
<span class="demo-text">My name is Mike and there are seven more people with name Mike in this building </span>
```

Now I want only the name "Mike" blanked out in the whole text. Below is my attempt which is incomplete:

.css file

```
 .demo-text {

}

 .index-pg {
   color: black;
   background: black;
   height: 20px;
 }
```

jquery file:

```
$(".demo-text").addClass('index-pg') ;
```

I am actually using a button to add or remove the "index-pg" class so that I can control when the names have to be blanked out. Adding and removing the class part is working fine. I am having issue with coding in jquery in such a way that it goes through individual words and looks for all the names "Mike" and applies the class only to that keyword.

Comment: Look for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38480136/2159528) to wrap "Mike" with a `span`, then add the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to place tags around matched word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479942/regex-to-place-tags-around-matched-word)

Comment: @Louys thanks for your suggestion Louys. I do need to learn more about regex since I am in early stage of learning I am going with other suggestions below for now. I will keep your suggestion in my learning list. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
$(".demo-text").html($(".demo-text").html().replace(/Mike/g, "<span class='index-pg'>Mike</span>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add following jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var str = jQuery(".demo-text").text();

  var res = replaceAll(str,'Mike','');

    jQuery(".demo-text").text(res);
});


function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

Here is the working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/manektech/37p5y2jk/5/

Comment: This squarely removes the word. OP wants to show/hide the word using a class.

Comment: Thank you @Mayank. But Louys is right I need the names in there but hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop inside `span` text and wrap your `keyword` with `span` with desire `class`.

```js
var keyWord = 'Mike';
var replaceMent = "<span class='index-pg'>" + keyWord + "</span>";
$(".demo-text").each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + keyWord + "\\b", "gi");
  txt = txt.replace(regex, replaceMent);
  $(this).html(txt);
});
```

```css
.demo-text {}

.index-pg {
  color: red;
  background: black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="demo-text">My name is Mike and there are seven more people with name Mike in this building </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all `demo-text` class and check if it has `Mike` in its text. If it has then you can add class as below:

```
$(".demo-text").each(function(e){
   let currentText = $(this).text();
   if (currentText.indexOf('Mike') >= 0) {
       $(this).text().replace(/Mike/g, "<span class='index-pg'>Mike</span>"));
   }
});
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi @Rohit thank you for your help but my system did not respond to this code.

Comment: You need to call this function when you are clicking on add/remove button.

Answer (score 0):

Add another span for the name

```
<span class="demo-text">My name is <span class="name-text">Mike</span> and there are seven more people with name Mike in this building </span>
```

.css file

```
.demo-text {

}
.name-text.index-pg {
  display:none;
 }
```

you are using a button add or remove "index-pg" class so that add/remove class only to that keyword(Mike).

```
$(".name-text").addClass('index-pg') ;
$(".name-text").removeClass('index-pg') ;
```

Comment: Just add display property none for hide element. Here we are using add class which  has display none css